# Authenticate with Firebase Anonymously offline

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to login when the user offline? If so, how does it work?
I'd like to keep the user anonymously until user connects to the network.

Comment: do you mean you want to store the firebase data locally on users mobile devices? and so they can have access to them while offline?

Comment: Just the log the user in when the user don't have the connection. And yes, I want to store only auth information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase Authentication requires a network connection for all types of authentication. It can't authenticate a user when there is no connection, not even anonymously.

A longer discussion of the topic can be found in [this thread from the firebase-talk mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/l4BO_V4vfmI).